# Removing the annoying icons Safari dumps on the dock

Tags: safari, dock, monterey

Safari on Monterey, has this annoying habit of cluttering the Dock with a load of icons.

See on the following pictures the dump of icons at the left side of the recycle bin.

[image]

How do I get rid of these icons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're minimised windows [as has already been mentioned].
If you want to be able to hang on to them rather than actually close them, then go to System Prefs > Dock & set 'Minimise windows into application icon'

[image]

Then they will not be separated out & will be under the Safari icon in the Dock on right click…

[image]

Answer (score 2):

They're the windows you've minimised.

- Stop minimising windows; close them or use them instead.
- Enable ‘Minimise windows into application icon’ in System Preferences Dock & Menu Bar which will put minimised windows into the app's Dock icon, hiding them from the Dock but they still remain open like normal (and you should still close or use them instead).

Answer (score 0):

Those look like minimized windows (clicking the Yellow `-` button at the top left of any window).

To confirm, you can right click Safari in the dock and select "See All Windows".

[image: Safari's Show All Windows option]

If you see those minimized screens, then you can choose to close them or keep them.